# TypeAhead not working with Firestore Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to implement search autocomplete for products in my firestore collection. The function only works for the first element of the list returned by the callback querying products from firestore. It returns no result for the rest even if user input matches listed products.

Here is my TypeAhead widget:

```
TypeAheadField<Product>(
      debounceDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      suggestionsCallback: (searchString) async {
        return await FirebaseCrud.getProductSuggestion(
                searchString, widget.categoryId)
            .then((value) => value.first);
      },
      itemBuilder: (context, itemData) {
        return ListTile(title: Text(itemData.productName));
      },
      onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
        print(suggestion.productName);
      },
    ),
```

Here is my callback implementation:

```
  static Future<Stream<List<Product>>> getProductSuggestion(
      String searchString, String categoryId) async {
    final products = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('products')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
                .map((doc) => Product.fromJson(doc.data()))
                .takeWhile((value) {
              print('name: ${value.productName.toLowerCase()}');
              print('searched: ${searchString.toLowerCase()}');

              return value.productName
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .contains(searchString.toLowerCase());
            }).toList());

    return products;
  }
```

The expected behavior is to suggest products on the fly while user is typing. It however only suggests if user input matches the first list item returned by the firestore callback. For the rest it just shows no result even if user input matches a product in firestore returned within the callback list of products.
I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.